# make top of circuitikz diagram align with top of item label within enumerate

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, circuitikz

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \begin{circuitikz} \draw
  (2,3) node[and port] (myand) {}
  (4,1) node[or port] (myor) {}
  (myand.out) -- (myor.in 1);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{enumerate}
```

is currently aligning like this

[image]

but I want it like this

[image]

I tried adding `[t]` after `\begin{ci...` like works for tabular and aligned, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, `circuitikz` environment is really a `tikzpicture`, so you can use all the options there.

To avoid to adjust manually the height, you can set the baseline to whatever coordinate of your diagram; in this case you seems to want the anchor corresponding to the first input of the NAND port:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(myand.in 1)] 
  \draw
  (2,3) node[and port] (myand) {}
  (4,1) node[or port] (myor) {}
  (myand.out) -- (myor.in 1);
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

you can find all the anchors available in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item xX  \raisebox{0.6\baselineskip}{% select shift according to your wish
  \begin{circuitikz}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)] 
    \draw   (2,3) node[and port] (myand) {}
            (4,1) node[or port] (myor) {}
            (myand.out) -- (myor.in 1);
  \end{circuitikz}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what's the number 0.6 ?

Comment: by it is multiplier of `\baselineskip`.  I estimated that for such amount the `tikzpicture` should be shifted above. for experiment change this value, you will see changes in picture position.

Comment: `0.6\baselineskip` is the distance from the baseline to the top of the text.  You can also use `\ht\strutbox`.